# Spring Boot War gives exception in Tomcat/Unix, but works on Windows

Tags: spring, unix, spring-boot, tomcat7

I am getting the below exception when trying to deploy the spring boot web application bundled in Windows to Unix server tomcat 7.but the same war is working fine in windows.

The war is created by maven (mvn clean install). Any idea how to resolve this ?

```
  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[r2144630a172].StandardContext[/helloweb]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:145)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create an instance of type [org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer$1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.doPrivileged(ApplicationContextFacade.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:652)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create an instance of type [org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer$1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1300)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade$1.run(ApplicationContextFacade.java:851)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.executeMethod(ApplicationContextFacade.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.invokeMethod(ApplicationContextFacade.java:796)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.doPrivileged(ApplicationContextFacade.java:767)
    ... 20 more
  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer$1
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1276)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Do you use the same Tomcat and Java versions on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: @dunni Yes both are using java 7

Comment: This looks like a Tomcat bug to me. It's trying to create an instance of an anonymous inner class which will always fail. What version of Tomcat 7 are you using?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson we are using the tomcat version 7.0.42

Comment: That's quite old. It won't necessarily fix your problem, but I'd recommend upgrading. A number of security vulnerabilities have been fixed since 7.0.42 was released. See https://tomcat.apache.org/security-7.html for details.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I am using the same tomcat version in my local windows machine and its working fine in windows.Bu not sure why its failing in linux

Comment: Do you have to deploy as a war file?  Can you try using the embedded tomcat container?  That's a huge advantage of Spring Boot.

Comment: @Bal Yes i have to deploy as a war file to the unix server.Other apps are dependent for this app